# Moving from Jquery 1.4.x to 1.7.x

Tags: jquery, migration

I have a huge project that I want to move from JQuery 1.4.x to 1.7.x

Where are the changes I need to be aware of when migrating, I know there is an issue with

```
.attr() and .prop()
```

Are there any other things I need to know, this is a production project so no mistakes can be allowed with behavior of the website.

Thank you.

Comment: You do have a development area to do the upgrade in, right?

Comment: Since 1.5 cross-sire requests require setting `$.support.cors = true;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"Where are the changes I need to be aware of when migrating..."*

See the [Version](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/) link in the API docs, which includes a link to [New or Changed in 1.7](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.7/), which contains a link to the [release notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/).

The API has links for each version...

[image]

Comment: I was thinking there is a better aggregation of the changes somewhere.